# I cannot bind the contacts in my arraylist can anyone tell me what i do wrong?ANDROID

Tags: android, events, android-edittext, android-contacts

```
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            c_Name.add(name);

                } }







            name_Val = (String[]) c_Name.toArray(new String[c_Name.size()]);
            //phone_Val= (String[]) c_Number.toArray(new String[c_Name.size()]);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name_Val);
            txtPhoneName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: All of the above code is in onCreate{}

Comment: As i am debugging i follow the code till txtPhoneName.setAdapter(adapter)and the ArrayAdapter adapter is filled with the contacts starting {null,"Name1","Name2"...} but when it comes to autocompletetextView it doesnt show anything, if insead i use fixed  String [] d={"NAME1","Name2","name3"} it binds them just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bind to an ArrayList? You can bind directly to cur using SimpleCursorAdapter.

what is autocompletetextView?

It's difficult to tell what exactly is going on because so much of the application is missing.

Also, what exactly are you trying to do? There may be an easier way to do it.